# Using enum class to handle user choice (polymorphic)

Tags: java, enums, polymorphism

I'm writing a java blackjack game, which includes input from the user according to a menu.

Right now I'm using a switch-case statement to handle the user choice, but everywhere I look people suggest not to use switch-case statements.

I wanted to use an enum class with the variables:

```
SPLIT, HIT, STAND, DOUBLE
```

According to the user's input (1-4) I want to invoke the appropriate method from the manager class that runs the game. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it like this:

```
int userInput = ... // Read a number 1..4
UserInputEnum inp = UserInputEnum.values()[userInput-1];
```

Comment: Thats a sneaky peice of code. Never came accross it before :)

Comment: If I do so, and then want to invoke a method from my manager class, should I make the enum class an inner class? because I need it to have access to private data members in the manager class.  @dasblinkenlight

Comment: another thing: what does the [] syntax after the values() method mean?

Comment: @DavidTzoor If `enum` needs access to parts of the class that must not be visible outside, a better approach would be putting the `enum` and the class into the same package, and change private methods to package-private.

Comment: @DavidTzoor `[]` has its normal meaning of accessing an array element by index.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I need it to have access to a private data member (a container to be exact). Is it possible to make a data member package-private?

Comment: @DavidTzoor Yes - simply remove `private` in front of the declaration. If you do not add `public` or `protected`, it's package-private.